# Which of the following sets are orthonormal?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I have three sets to determine whether they're orthonormal or not. These are;

(a) $\{1,\frac{x}{\sqrt2}+\frac{x^3}{\sqrt2},\frac{x^2}{\sqrt2}-\frac{x^4}{\sqrt2}$}

(b) $\{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{2}, -\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2}, \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{2}$}

(c) $\{\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{2x^4}{3}+\frac{2x^6}{3}, \frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{3}-\frac{2x^7}{3}$}

The inner product for two arbitrary polynomials is

$$a.b= \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_k$$

I know that to prove that they are I need to do the dot product of each pair and for them to all equal 0 and that the magnitude of each should equal 1 for the sets to be determined as orthonormal but I'm having trouble starting off with this exercise, the x's are throwing me off and I'm wondering if there's something else I have to do before working out the magnitude and scalar product. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Orthonormal in which inner product space? You haven't specified it.

Comment: Just put it in now, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: There is still an issue of which vector space you are using with that inner-product. Possibly, are you considering a space of polynomials? So that, for example, the vector $a + bx + cx^2$ has components $(a,b,c,0,...)$ in the standard basis $\{1, x, x^2,...\}$.

Comment: Yes, its for two arbitrary polynomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: just convert the polynomial into vectors. For the first set, the highest degree of the polynomials is 4 so you need at least 5 coordinates to take into account all the non-zero coefficients:
$$1\rightarrow (1,0,0,0,0), \frac{x}{\sqrt2}+\frac{x^3}{\sqrt2}\rightarrow (0,1/\sqrt2,0,1/\sqrt2,0), \frac{x^2}{\sqrt2}-\frac{x^4}{\sqrt2}\rightarrow (0,0,1/\sqrt2,0,1/\sqrt2)$$
then take the usual scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^5$.
Now
$$\begin{align*}
&(1,0,0,0,0)\cdot(1,0,0,0,0)=1 \rightarrow\mbox{it is a unit vector}\\
&(1,0,0,0,0)\cdot(0,1/\sqrt2,0,1/\sqrt2,0)=0 \rightarrow\mbox{they are orthogonal}
\end{align*}$$
and so on. Now are you able to start your exercise?

Comment: why is that necessary?

Comment: @Carry on Smiling You are absolutely right, but Sophie broke my heart!

Comment: If that's enough to break your heart you're really screwed m8.

Comment: @Carry on Smiling Nice comment... anyway I carry on smiling.

Answer (score 0):

In polynomial space, the standard orthonormal basis (with respect to the inner-product you gave above) is $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, ...\}$ and so, for example, a polynomial such as $2 + 3x^2 - 4x^4$ can be represented by the vector $(2, 0, 3, 0, -4, 0, ...)$ since
$$2\cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 3 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 + (-4) \cdot x^4 = 2 + 3x^2 - 4x^4.$$

In your case, for (a), you then have the identifications:
$$
\left\{1,\frac{x}{\sqrt2}+\frac{x^3}{\sqrt2},\frac{x^2}{\sqrt2}-\frac{x^4}{\sqrt2}\right\} \longrightarrow \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\0\\0\\0\\ 0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1/\sqrt{2}\\0\\1/\sqrt{2}\\0\\0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0\\1/\sqrt{2}\\0\\-1/\sqrt{2}\\ 0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix} \right\}
$$

Now that you have these understood componentwise, you can use the inner-product you have given.